# psycopg2 query for variable length values

Tags: python, psycopg2

How can I construct a Postgres query for a variable length list of tuples with psycopg2? For example, in the the query below how do I parameterize over the ('a','b'), ('a','a')?

```py
cursor.execute(
  "SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('a','b'), ('a','a')) AS t (l,r)")
```

The naive approach of

```py
cursor.execute(
  "SELECT * FROM (VALUES %s) AS t (l,r)",
  ([('a','b'), ('a','a')],))
```

fails with a syntax error as a single array value is inserted rather than a sequence of tuples.

Comment: why you first an string the use it in `cursor.execute()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use string concentration to create `%s` placeholders in your query:

```
tValues = [('a','b'), ('d','e'), ('f','g')]
query = "SELECT * FROM (VALUES %s) AS t (l,r)" % ''.join(' %s,' for t in tValues)[:-1] # remove the last comma!
print(cur.mogrify(query, tValues))
cur.execute(query, tValues)
print(cur.fetchall())
```

Out:

```
b"SELECT * FROM (VALUES  ('a', 'b'), ('d', 'e'), ('f', 'g')) AS t (l,r)"
[('a', 'b'), ('d', 'e'), ('f', 'g')]
```